# Select data in tables by conditions between 2 tables which is not linked

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a large select with a lot of inner joins.

In the select I have an *array_agg* function for one set of data.

This array contains only a column of a table, but now I want to append at the end of the array data from another table. The data I need to add is not directly linked with the previous table where I need the column.

Query example:

```
select
    origin_table.x,
    origin_table.y,
    array_agg(table1.data) ...
from
    origin_table
inner join ... inner join ... full join table1 on
    table.origin_table_id = origin_table.id ...
group by
    ...
```

Result array:

```
ID 1: example_data, {baba, bobo}
ID 2: example_data, {bibi, bubu}
```

Example of my tables:

```
table 1:

 id | data    | origin_table_id
----+---------+----------
  1 |    baba | 1
  2 |    bobo | 1     
  3 |    bibi | 2    
  4 |    bubu | 2     

table 2:

id | data_bis 
---+---------
 1 | byby 
 2 | bebe

origin table:

id | table2_id
---+----------
 1 | 2
 2 | 1
```

Expected result with the 3 tables:

```
ID 1: example_data, {baba, bobo, bebe}
ID 2: example_data, {bibi, bubu, byby}
```

But got :

```
ID 1: example_data, {baba, bobo, bebe, byby}
ID 2: example_data, {bibi, bubu, bebe, byby}
```

What I need is:

How to have all the data of table 1 which respect the condition and append to it the unique table 2 data but not all elements of the table.

Comment: table 2 can have more value for id= 1?

Comment: @mkRabbani Yes the table have more than 2 columns

Comment: I am asking for row. currently there only 'byby' for id 1, any possibility of have more value like 'blabla' for same id 1?

Comment: @mkRabbani Yes all id in table 2 are unique, but in the origin table can have multiple row with the table2_id equal example ```id = 3, table2_id = 1```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query..

```
create table tab1 (id integer,data character varying,origin_table_id integer);

insert into tab1
select 1,'baba',1
union all
select 2,'bobo',1
union all
select 3,'bibi',2
union all
select 4,'bubu',2

create table tab2 (id integer,data_bis character varying);

insert into tab2
select 1,'byby'
union all
select 2,'bebe'

create table OriginalTable (id integer,table2_id integer);

insert into OriginalTable
select 1,2
union all
select 2,1

select * from OriginalTable

select origin_table_id,data
from tab1
union all
select OriginalTable.table2_id,data_bis
from OriginalTable 
join tab2 on tab2.id = OriginalTable.id
order by origin_table_id
```

Result:

```
1;"baba"
1;"bobo"
1;"bebe"
2;"bibi"
2;"bubu"
2;"byby"
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, in my case what i get is ```"baba","bobo","bibi","bubu","byby","bebe"```

Answer (score 0):

I can give you some idea and sample code to achieve your requirement.

First you can UNION ALL table 'table 1' and 'table 2' using the relation table 'origin table'.

```
WITH CTE
AS
(

    SELECT AA.id,AA.data_bis,AA.origin_table_id
    FROM table_1 AA

    UNION ALL

    SELECT NULL id, A.data_bis,B.id origin_table_id
    FROM table_2 A
    INNER JOIN origin_table B
    ON A.id = B.table2_id
)

SELECT * FROM CTE
```

After applying UNION ALL, data will be looks like below-

```
data_bis    origin_table_id
baba        1
bobo        1
bibi        2
bubu        2
byby        2
bebe        1
```

Now you can apply 'string_agg' on your data as below-

```
SELECT origin_table_id,string_agg(DISTINCT  data_bis,',') 
FROM CTE
GROUP BY origin_table_id
```

And the output will be-

```
origin_table_id     string_agg
1                   baba,bebe,bobo
2                   bibi,bubu,byby
```

Now, you can apply further JOINING to this data as per your requirement. You can check [DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=598281e49669e9ff58672056674c0ebb)

> Please keep in mind hat this is not exact solution of your issue. Just idea...

Comment: Thank you, but i think i'm gonna do this in another query and append my data in my API. I think is more easier.